# How to fix ValueError time date does not match format when converting from string to datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to convert a string to datetime and keep getting the error: ValueError: time data 'Mon, 22 Apr 2019 17:04:38 +0200 (CEST)' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z'

```
from datetime import datetime
s = "Mon, 22 Apr 2019 17:04:38 +0200 (CEST)"
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z')
```

What am i missing?

Comment: I just noticed that (CEST) and %Z is not the same. By removing the (CEST) using something like s = s[0:len(s)-7] and removing %Z, it works. Just want to make sure im not messing up the date in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%Z is generally used for converting *into* string format.  In any case, it is the offset, not the name of the time zone.

The rest of your code is valid, however:

```
s = "Mon, 22 Apr 2019 17:04:38 +0200"
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

Comment: For one it should be noted that `%Z` as a strptime directive is only good for *igonring* GMT or UTC literals. It doesn't lead to aware datetime objects. As a strftime directive, it gives you a time zone abbreviation like CEST - which is not nice either (no IANA name). Other than that, `%z` does a good job here but only gives a static UTC offset, so not to use in combination with timedelta arithmetic (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66966226/10197418)).

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` only comes with the ability to parse `UTC` and whatever local time zone is listed in `time.tzname`. It can't match `(CEST)` because it doesn't know what timezone that is (It would also be redundant because you defined the timezone using the offset `+0200`).

You will need to implement your own `(CEST)` using `datetime.tzinfo` or by importing an external library like `pytz` or `pendulum` in order to parse `(CEST)` from a string into a `datetime.timezone`.

Also, don't forget to include parenthesis`()` in your match string.

Answer (score 0):

This code passes, however, I do not know what happens to 'CEST' once it is converted into the string.

```
from datetime import datetime
tz = 'CEST'
s = "Mon, 22 Apr 2019 17:04:38 +0200 " + tz
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z ' + tz)
```

Comment: This does not address the question posted.

Comment: @Prune I changed it; is this more appropriate?

Comment: It's somewhat better.  You've bypassed the problem, but didn't give OP any particular explanation or insight.

Comment: @Prune does it deserve a removal of the -1? It’s a hard life down here