# Python datetime strptime() does not match format

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I get the following error in which you can see the time data and the format I am using

`time data '20:07:35 EEDT Wed Mar 31 2021' does not match format '%H:%M:%S %Z %a %b %d %Y'`

I used the directives from [here](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime) and I see that the format matches the description of each directive.
Can you see what is the issue here?

Comment: The problem seems to be the timezone

Comment: It doesn'T accept 'EEDT'. It works however for 'UTC'

Comment: @peter `%Z` accepts `GMT` or `UTC` ***but*** it doesn't parse to aware datetime. That can lead to unexpected results since you might expect UTC but you get local time since Python treats naive datetime like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime

time = '20:07:35 EEDT Wed Mar 31 2021'
time = time.replace('EEDT', '+0300')
datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S %z %a %b %d %Y')
```

Comment: Like the idea, but the UTC offset will be static, i.e. timedelta arithmetic might give unexpected results due to DST. And of course this will *only* work if the input contains `EEDT`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with `EEDT`. If you ignore EEDT(quickfix, not ideal), then your code may look like:

```
text = '20:07:35 EEDT Wed Mar 31 2021';
fmt = '%H:%M:%S EEDT %a %b %d %Y';
datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
```

--edit--

parsing datetime with timezone is difficult to pure datetime module. I'm not big expert, but `pytz` or `python-datetutil` should be good choice, according to this page: https://medium.com/@nqbao/python-timezone-and-daylight-savings-e511a0093d0

Comment: The problem with including a literal `EEDT` in the parsing directive is that this makes the code specific. It will break for other datetime, e.g. if the UTC offset is EEST. And it will leave you with naive datetime (tzinfo==None), which Python treats as local time by default -> can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: You are right. But I suggest my sollution as temporary/quickfix. Better sollution is to use dedicated library, which has been tested against such scenarios.

Comment: yup, the thing is at some point you must map from abbreviation to IANA time zone, which is the standard. But abbreviated time zones are ambiguous - see e.g. the *BS*Ts on https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ - there are 3 of them. That gives standard libs a hard time and users a headache ^^

Comment: Am I correctly understand, that OP should have also aproximated location for theirs timezone-aware datetime strings to properly parse them? I.e location should be used to correctly convert IANA timezone to UTC?

Comment: yes, but that's a rather sophisticated approach. most of the time, a simple UTC offset will do, as you can tell from the the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can map the abbreviated time zone to a [IANA time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) by [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s parser:

```
import dateutil

s = '20:07:35 EEDT Wed Mar 31 2021'

tzmapping = {"EEDT": dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/Athens'),
             "EEST": dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/Athens')} # add more if needed...

dtobj = dateutil.parser.parse(s, tzinfos=tzmapping)
```

that will give you

```
dtobj
# >>> datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 31, 20, 7, 35, tzinfo=tzfile('Europe/Athens'))
dtobj.utcoffset()
# >>> datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800) # UTC+3
```

Note that timedelta arithmetic works correctly, i.e. includes DST changes:

```
from datetime import timedelta
dtobj -= timedelta(7) # DST change: dtobj is now EEST, UTC+2
dtobj.utcoffset()
# >>> datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested in different approach for similar, like GMT and BST or EEST and EEDT, it can be represented like this:

```
import datetime

try:
    Time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(DropTm,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S GMT %Y")
except:
    Time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(DropTm,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S BST %Y")
```

In your situation it will be:

```
import datetime

try:
    Time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(SomeValue,"%H:%M:%S EEDT %a %b %d %Y")
except:
    Time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(SomeValue,"%H:%M:%S EEST %a %b %d %Y")
```

Where is "SomeValue" your data!!

It did worked for me and do not need any other libraries! Good Luck with coding!!!