# How do I parse timestamp strings which contain BST (British Summer Time) into a timezone aware datetime timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

I have timestamps of the format "25-Oct-20 1:00:00 AM GMT" and "25-Oct-20 12:00:00 AM BST" and I wish to parse them into a timezone aware datetime. I have tried using the strptime format "%d-%b-%y %I:%M:%S %p %Z"

However the %Z argument of datetime.strptime does not recognize BST as a valid input, and I can not figure out the "correct" way to handle parsing daylight savings times.

Comment: Are you user that's not Bangalore Standard Time or some other acronym? There's no standard for these three-letter acronyms. IST for example is India, Israel and Ireland S(tandard/ummer) Time. *DON'T* use `BST`

Comment: From [the datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) on `%Z`: `strptime() only accepts certain values for %Z: 1)
any value in time.tzname for your machine’s locale 2) 
the hard-coded values UTC and GMT`. So `BST` means whatever your machine thinks it means, if it can handle it at all. On my machine `time.tzname` returns only `('EET', 'EEST')`

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, thanks for replying. Unfortunately I don't have a choice but to use BST, I am reading data from another service which uses BST to designate daylight savings i.e. British Summer Time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python datetime strptime() does not match format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66965723/python-datetime-strptime-does-not-match-format) - if you search here on SO, there are many more questions relating to "`%Z` does not match time zone abbreviation"

Comment: Side note: although `%Z` works for GMT, it is a bad choice since it doesn't parse to aware datetime.

Comment: @MrFruppes yes that looks like it would work thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error from `dateutil`, it says something like:

```
UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname BST identified but not understood.  
Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware
datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
```

In other words, you can pass in a dictionary that maps timezone aliases (like "BST") to appropriate timezone information.  Maybe something like:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> import dateutil.tz
>>> BST = dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/London')
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('25-Oct-20 12:00:00 AM BST', tzinfos={'BST': BST})
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 25, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London'))
```

Comment: @Darragh1066 that's because the real problem is the use of the ambiguous acronym. Look white this code does. It uses the de-facto standard IANA timezone name to create a new "timezone" abbreviation. There are [7 timezones with the BST acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BST). Your code will work only for one of them

Comment: @Darragh1066 the real solution would be to use the IANA timezone name in the string from the start

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the world seems far from ideal (real) sometimes; here, even if you create a datetime object with a timezone object derived from a proper IANA time zone name, `strftime` `%Z` gives you back `BST`! It's a pain ^^

Comment: @MrFuppes that's a `strftime` bug. Most languages and standard libraries (I'd say all) weren't written with proper timezone support, before ecommerce sites had to handle requests from all over the world, including DST rules that changed with 2 weeks notice (Egypt a few years ago).